# The Closure of a connected set is a connected set

Tags: general-topology

If i suppose that $\overline{A}$ is not connected then $\begin{cases} \overline{A}=U\cup V\\ U\neq\emptyset, V\neq\emptyset\\U\cap V=\emptyset\end{cases}$ where $U,V$ are open in $\overline{A}$

We know that $A$ is connected and $A\subset \overline{A}$ then $A\subset U$ or $A\subset V$

How to continue?

Thank you

Comment: Since $U,V$ are nonempty, choose points in them...

Comment: Ok let $x\in U$ and $y\in V$ wht i must do after ?

Comment: This is a "follow your nose" proof. What you should be doing is to look at the next thing in front of your nose. Since $x \in U$, and $U$ is open in $\overline A$, and $\overline A$ is the closure of $A$, ...

Comment: Rather than continually posting and deleting questions when they are downvoted, please edit your questions to improve them. I've seen this happen quite a few times.

Comment: @LeeMosher if $x\in U$ open then $U\cap A\neq \emptyset,$ i don't see how to find a contradiction withe the fact that $A$ is connected

Comment: @LeeMosher we use that $A\subset U$ or $A\subset V$ or not ?

Answer (score 5):

Let $f:\bar A\to \{0,1\}$ be a continuous map. Since $A$ is connected, $f(A)=\{ 0 \}$ or $f(A)= \{ 1 \}$. Suppose $f(A)=\{ 0 \}$, then $f^{-1}(0)$ is a closed subset which contains $A$, so $\bar A\subset f^{-1}(0)$. Same argument if $f(A)=1$. We deduce that $f$ is constant. Thus $\bar A$ is connected.

Comment: Sir, please can you elaborate. How $f$ is constant map? My attempt: let $\bar A\subset f^{-1}(0)$. if $f$ were not constant then there exists some $x\in\bar A$ such that $f(x)=1$ but then what? Please help.

Comment: It's constant since in either case the whole space $\overline{A}$ gets mapped to a single element....

Comment: Why does $f$ being constant imply that $\overline{A}$ is connected?

Answer (score 5):

Since $U,V$ are nonempty and open in $\overline A$, and since $\overline A$ is the closure of $A$, each of $U,V$ has nonempty intersection with $A$. The sets $U'=U \cap A$, $V'=V \cap A$ therefore have the following properties: $A = U' \cup V'$; $U' \ne \emptyset$ and $V' \ne \emptyset$; $U',V'$ are open in $A$; $U' \cap V' = \emptyset$. It follows that $A$ is disconnected.

Comment: so we don't use the fact that $A\subset U$ or $A\subset V$?

Comment: I am continuing the proof by contradiction that you started in your question: starting from the assumption that $\overline A$ is disconnected, one proves that $A$ is disconnected.

Comment: in my proof i used the fact that $A$ is connected then $A\subset U$ or $A\subset V$ can i continue with this and found a contradiction ?

Comment: please why U' is open in A ?

Comment: @LeeMosher in your proof above you say that "each of $U, V$ has nonempty intersection with $A$": why is that the case?

Comment: Every open subset of a topological space (in this case $\overline A$) has nonempty intersection with every dense subset of that space (in this case $A$) @lorenzo

Comment: @LeeMosher I got stuck working on a proof of this same result but in the setting of metric spaces (in the book I'm reading the notion of topological space isn't used) so I can't use this result. Do you have any hint about how I could proceed in this case? (In fact I was writing a question about this when I found this thread, that's why I'm asking here) I tried arguing by contradiction but I only managed to discover that being $A$ connected then either $A\subseteq U$ and $A\cap V=\emptyset$ or $A\subseteq V$ and $A\cap V=\emptyset$ and also that either $cl(U)=cl(A)$ or $cl(V)=cl(A)$.

Comment: My comment with the words "topological space" remains true if you replace those words with "metric space" (when you learn topology, you will learn that a metric space is a special kind of topological space). If you have any further followup questions, I suggest that you post your own question on math.stackexchange.