# How to show that the space is connected but not locally-connected.

Tags: general-topology

Given that $I = [0,1]$, the following is a subspace of $R^2$:

$$X = (\{1\} × I) ∪ \left(I × \left(\{0\} \cup\{ \frac{1}{n} \mid n \in \Bbb N \}\right)\right)$$

How can one show that it is connected but not locally-connected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is connected, because it is path connected. Given any point $(x,y)\in X$ there is a straight linear path connecting $(x,y)$ to $(1,y)$. Then there's a straight linear path connecting $(1,y)$ to $(1,1)$. Meaning every point can be connected to $(1,1)$, and so $X$ is path connected.

Not being locally connected is a bit more difficult. Consider $v=(0,0)$ and let $U\subseteq X$ be a small enough neighbourhood of $v$, say $U=\big((-\infty,1/2)\times \mathbb{R}\big)\cap X$. The reason I choose such $U$ is because I don't want $\{1\}\times I$ to intersect with it.

Now let $V\subseteq U$ be any subneighbourhood of $U$. Consider the projection $\pi:V\to\mathbb{R}$, $\pi(x,y)=y$. Since $\{1\}\times I$ does not intersect $U$, then it does not intersect $V$ as well. And thus the image $im(\pi)$ of $\pi$ is some infinite subset of $A=\{0\}\cup\{\frac{1}{n}\}_{n=1}^\infty$. But in $A$ every point except for $0$ is clopen. Let $r\in im(\pi)$ be some non-zero point. Then $\pi^{-1}(r)$ is clopen as well, meaning $V$ is not connected.

Comment: When you write $π:V→R$ projection, what topologies do you assume for $V$ and $R$? Do you mean that $V$ has a subspace topology of $R^2$ and $A$ a subspace topology of $R$?

Comment: Yes, $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ have the standard Euclidean topology and everything else has subspace topology.

Comment: Why is $π$ here assumed to be continuous? And also why is it important that $\{1\} × I$ not intersect U and hence V?

Comment: I get now why it's continuous, taking inverse of any open set will yield an open set in this case. What about intersection with $\{1\}× I$?

Comment: I get now. Otherwise the projection map might unnecessarily map $y$ values between "horizontal lines" $1/n$ and A in worst case will not consist of clopen singleton points.

Comment: @СССР Projections (and their restrictions as in our case) are always continuous. That is one of the characteristics of the product topology. It is important that $\{1\}\times I$ does not intersect $U$ in order to ensure that the image $im(\pi)$ is contained in $A=\{0\}\cup\{1/n\}_{n=1}^\infty $. Yes, we want those clopen subsets. But the vertical line $A$ is an obstacle. Drawing a picture and all those objects may give you the right intuition.

Comment: Do you know why a subspace of $X$, defined as $Y = X \setminus \{ (\frac{1}{2},0) \}$ is also connected although it is not path-connected anymore?

Comment: I know it has to do with a fact that $Y$ is open in $X$, so therefore $(0,\frac{1}{2})$ is not open in $Y$ and neither can be $(\frac{1}{2}, 1)$ (and no subset of them). So if $Y$ were to be divided as two open sets $A$ and $B$ then wlog. it must hold that $((0,\frac{1}{2}) \cup (\frac{1}{2}, 1)) \subsetneq A$. But I don't know how to formulate the proof from there. I know that $B$ can't be open because you can't find an open ball in $R^2$ that would intersect $X$ and thus $Y$ to obtain an *open* B. I just don't know how to formulate it rigorously.

Comment: Have a look at this proof (the first answer): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1634855/the-closure-of-a-connected-set-is-a-connected-set/1634903 The point here is that the closure of connected space is connected. You can generalize the proof so that the same applies to any set in between. Meaning let $Y=X\backslash (I\times \{0\})$. Then $Y$ is connected and thus so is any subset $D$ between $Y\subseteq D\subseteq\overline{Y}$, while $\overline{Y}=X$.

Comment: Funny thing is that statement was in *H.Herrlich's Topology* book that i use and it never came to my mind. Thanks a lot.